# Displaying name of two users from a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Keeping this clean and to the point:

I have two MySQL tables, users (id, nick) and bans (id, banned, bannedBy, length).
I want to display in a table a list of bans, but instead of displaying the banned ID and the bannedBy ID, I want to display their nick.
I can use an JOIN to get the nick of one of them, in something like this:

```
SELECT bans.id,bans.banned,bans.bannedBy,bans.length,users.nick
FROM bans
JOIN users ON users.id=bans.banned
```

But then I can't get the bannedBy's nick, and vice verca.

I hope I was clear, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to join `users` table twice, on different keys.

```
SELECT
    bans.id,
    bans.banned,
    bans.bannedBy,
    bans.length,
    u.nick as 'banedNick',
    u2.nick as 'bannedByNick'
FROM
    bans
JOIN 
    users u ON users.id = bans.banned
JOIN
    users u2 ON users.id = bans.bannedBy
```

Comment: Thanks, I am newbie and the help is much appreciated. Turns out that once you "name" the table u or u2, then you need to stick with it right on. SELECT
    bans.id,
    bans.banned,
    bans.bannedBy,
    bans.length,
    u.nick as 'banedNick',
    u2.nick as 'bannedByNick'
FROM
    bans
JOIN 
    users u ON u.id = bans.banned
JOIN
    users u2 ON u2.id = bans.bannedBy

Answer (score 1):

You can use two joins:

```
SELECT bans.id,bans.banned,b.nick as bannedBy,bans.length,u.nick
FROM bans
JOIN users u ON u.users.id=bans.banned
JOIN users b ON b.users.id=bans.bannedBy
```